# How to separate a new line using line_tokenize or word_tokenize using nltk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Tried tokenizing a paragraph with new lines with a word_tokenize and sent_tokenize but its not recognizing the new lines.

tried separating it in paragraphs by splitting it in new line but still not working.

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
para="the new line \n new char"
sent=sent_tokenize(para)
print(sent)
```

output:

```
['the new line \n new char']
```

It's working if the data is specified in a string format in python but fails when I extract from a docx file

for data in python, i'm using

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
para="the new line \n new char"
paragraphs = [p for p in para.split('\n') if p]
par3=[sent_tokenize(par) for par in paragraphs]
print(par3)
```

output:

```
[['the new line'], [' new char']]
```

PS: I am reading the data from a doc file with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: `sent_tokenize()` does not split the data according to a new line.  It looks for sentence terminator like **.** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NLTK, `sent_tokenize` is a statistical algorithm. It's an implementation of the Punkt algorithm from [Kiss and Strunk (2006)](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/coli.2006.32.4.485)

The `word_tokenize` is a rule-based (regex search and replace) algorithm extended from the original [Treebank word tokenizer from the Penn TreeBank project](https://waybackmachine.org/web/20070810211926/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed)

To separate a string using the `\n` symbol, simply do a `str.split('\n'`), e.g.

```
>>> s = 'abc\ndef'
>>> print(s)
abc
def
>>> s.split('\n')
['abc', 'def']
```

Comment: so when i split it when its a normal text in a python variable it works, but fails when i use getText in python to extract the data from a docx file.
Also i checked the extract from the docx file after it got extracted and the new line just vanishes and comes bundled up in the same data.
Eg.
_"Jerry McGuire
 <new line>NewYork"_ in docx file is extracted as 

**Jerry McGuireNewYork**